# ttest or f-test where you expect the price of one variable to be higher than the other

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance

I am having a problem formulating a null and alternate hypothesis for the question below:

"We expect the price of a refurbished phone to be higher than that of a used phone with no defects (holding the rest of the explanatory variables constant). 
Test whether the regression results support this expectation 
(at the 5% level).

**Hint:** Do we need any test statistics here?"

My thinking:

- Null Hypothesis $H_0$: $\beta_{\text{refurbished}}$ = 0
- Alternative Hypothesis $H_A$: $\beta_{\text{refurbished}} \neq 0$

I am told to expect the price of a refurbished phone to be higher than that of a used phone with no defects, but, the price of a refurbished phone could possible be lower than that of a used phone with no defects, despite what I am told to expect.

Comment: I don't understand the "hint" but perhaps it is that if you use notation you should define it. The statement of the hypothesis is unclear because of the unnecessary notation. Additionally it is clear enough that it should be a one tailed test. If this is homework, please tag "self study".

Comment: @AdamO I don't get the hint either. I am wondering if the Alternative Hypothesis should be one-tailed as in Beta(refb) > 0 or if this is best as a two sided ttest? Any thoughts? I will flag for self study.

Comment: I would say that this is a one-sided test. You're not interested in testing if new phones are less expensive, only if they are more expensive. While you can get the direction of the effect even if you do a two-sided test, that reduces the power to reject the null hypothesis, since you do not have to split $\alpha$ between the two tails.

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to be asking you to formally state a hypothesis.

The "hint" makes a critical fallacy of conflating a "test statistic" with the "effect of interest". In our case we're interested in average price of a phone, it's "expectation". So we either define the average price of either type of phone, or the difference between them. If *I* were grading and I see "beta" and "refb" without any definition, I'd mark it incorrect.

The second point of consideration is the appropriate direction of effect under the null. We wish to prove that refurbished phones are more expensive. Therefore assume the opposite. As an example:

$$\mathcal{H}_0 : \mu_{\text{used phone}} \ge \mu_{\text{refurbished phone}}$$

That is, used phones are either equal to or more expensive than refurbished ones. Providing evidence to the contrary and testing for statistical significance can be quantified with the $p$ value.

Comment: I would guess a little differently about the hint. To me the hint is implying that we may not need a hypothesis -- or at least a null hypothesis of no difference -- for an effect that is obvious or expected. We may not need even a confidence interval!

Comment: @NickCox The specific text from the question regarding *expectation* and *test* strongly suggest to me that the premise, or the "null hypothesis" is one of stochastic ordering. If it were of strict inequality, a decision rule could be setup, but it seems natural to consider pricing, and data on pricing, as being a random variable. Whether "(holding the rest of the explanatory variables constant)" is meant to imply that *all* causal variables have been accounted for seems implausible and bizarre for an elementary stats question.

Comment: Ho hum. I may have more experience than you in reading other people's material on elementary statistics (various reviews of mine on amazon.com are one sample), but whether or not that's true I don't expect to find rigour lurking behind informal wording.  Without a reference or a fuller context it's hard to take speculation further.